# Rails: Keeping user spoofing checks DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

In a fit of unoriginality, I'm writing a blog application using Ruby on Rails. My `PostsController` contains some code that ensures that the logged in user can only edit or delete their own posts.

I tried factoring this code out into a private method with a single argument for the flash message to display, but when I did this and tested it by editing another author's post, I got an `ActionController::DoubleRenderError` - "Can only render or redirect once per action".

How can I keep these checks [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)? The obvious approach is to use a before filter but the `destroy` method needs to display a different flash.

Here's the relevant controller code:

```
before_filter :find_post_by_slug!, :only => [:edit, :show]

def edit

  # FIXME Refactor this into a separate method
  if @post.user != current_user
    flash[:notice] = "You cannot edit another author’s posts."
    redirect_to root_path and return
  end
  ...
end

def update 
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  # FIXME Refactor this into a separate method
  if @post.user != current_user
    flash[:notice] = "You cannot edit another author’s posts."
    redirect_to root_path and return
  end
  ...
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:slug])

  # FIXME Refactor this into a separate method
  if @post.user != current_user
    flash[:notice] = "You cannot delete another author’s posts."
    redirect_to root_path and return
  end
  ...
end

private
def find_post_by_slug!
  slug = params[:slug]
  @post = Post.find_by_slug(slug) if slug
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @post.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The before filter approach is still an ok option.  You can gain access to which action was requested using the controller's `action_name` method.

```
before_filter :check_authorization

...

protected

def check_authorization
  @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
  if @post.user != current_user
    flash[:notice] = (action_name == "destroy") ? 
      "You cannot delete another author’s posts." : 
      "You cannot edit another author’s posts."
    redirect_to root_path and return false
  end
end
```

Sorry for that ternary operator in the middle there.  :)  Naturally you can do whatever logic you like.

You can also use a method if you like, and avoid the double render by explicitly returning if it fails.  The key here is to return so that you don't double render.

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
  return unless authorized_to('delete')
  ...
end

protected

def authorized_to(mess_with)
  if @post.user != current_user
    flash[:notice] = "You cannot #{mess_with} another author’s posts."
    redirect_to root_path and return false
  end
  return true
end
```

You could simplify it more (in my opinion) by splitting out the different parts of behavior (authorization, handling bad authorization) like this:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
  punt("You cannot mess with another author's post") and return unless author_of(@post)
  ...
end

protected

def author_of(post)
  post.user == current_user
end

def punt(message)
  flash[:notice] = message
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Personally, I prefer to offload all of this routine work to a plugin.  My personal favorite authorization plugin is [Authorization](http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin/tree/master/).  I've used it with great success for the last several years.

That would refactor your controller to use variations on:

```
permit "author of :post"
```

Comment: Don't make a query before the auth check!

Comment: @Pedro You're going to have to explain to me how you can check authorization (not authentication) based on a specific model before you have a copy of that model.  :)

Comment: Your authorization method makes 0 queries.
You make a find by before checking if the user is authorized or not.

Comment: Btw I'm talking about the second example.

Comment: You have to pull the model out of the database (in one method or another) to see if the owner owns it.  That's the unavoidable reality of model-dependent authorizations.

Comment: Excellent answer - thanks. I went with your second example in the end (authorized_to). I tried the final example but it actually still raises the double render exception.

The Authorization plugin feels a little heavyweight for this, but I'll certainly investigate it for future apps.

Comment: The other example should still work -- just be sure to have "and return" after punt.  My personal opinion on leveraging third party plugins/libraries is that while it may feel heavyweight for little projects, you probably end up spending as much time reinventing a wheel that does less as learning and leveraging another library that does more than you need.  You never have to use everything, after all.

Comment: I did have "and return" after punt. I copied your example exactly and it didn't work.

Comment: I suspect you're missing something somewhere.  And cargo culting will only get you so far; you should work to understand the what and the why of every line of code you write.  Then you'll be able to debug simple problems yourself -- or more likely, avoid them.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to change the message to something that fits both: "You cannot mess with another author's posts."

Comment: Yeah, but I don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the ugly* return in that last solution, you can use an around filter and conditionally yield only if the user is authorized.

```
around_filter :check_authorization, :only => [:destroy, :update]

private
def check_authorization
    @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    if @post.user == current_user
        yield
    else
        flash[:notice] = case action_name
        when "destroy"
            "You cannot delete another author's posts."
        when "update"
            "You cannot edit another author's posts."
        end
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

*-- that's my preference, though code-wise it's perfectly valid. I just find that style-wise, it tends to not fit.

I also should add I haven't tested this and am not 100% certain it would work, though it should be easy enough to try.